# What is the difference between "in such a manner as to" and "so as to"?

Tags: to-infinitive

Are these two terms interchangeable? For example, can "in such a manner as to" in the following sentence I found on a US university's website be replaced with "so as to" ? :

> No person may park or operate a motor vehicle on the campus in such a
>   manner as to cause damage to any university property.

Comment: The main difference is that ***in such a manner*** is much more likely in legal documents and older texts, because the use of ***so*** in this sense wasn't common 200-300 years ago. In the UK, the [Plain English Campaign](http://www.plainenglish.co.uk/) might well write to the college administrators suggesting they get with the 21st century, but I doubt that's likely in the US.

Comment: ...imho it would be ludicrously pedantic to argue that ***so*** implies ***in order to*** (a volitional act) - but of course, IANAL. They are a law unto themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In contemporary English *so as* is not equivalent to *in such a manner as*.

To do X 'in such a manner as' to Y designates any case in which the **manner** or method of your doing X causes Y to happen, regardless of your intention. You may intend to do X correctly and you may think you're doing X correctly; but if you cause Y to happen you've broken the rule.

To do X 'so as to' Y would designate any case in which you do X with the **intention** of causing Y to happen. You may be incompetent and in fact **not** cause Y to happen; but if you were **trying** to make Y happen you would have broken the rule.